# Two text file comparison with grep

Tags: text, grep, comparison, pipeline

I have two files (a.txt, b.txt)

`a.txt` is a list of English words (one word in ever row)
`b.txt` contains in every row: a number, a space character, a 5-65 char long string
(for example `b.txt` can contain: `1234 dsafaaraehawada`)

I would like to know which row in `b.txt` contains words from `a.txt` and how many of them?

Example input:

a.txt

```
green
apple
bar
```

b.txt

```
1212 greensdsdappleded
12124 dfsfsd
123 bardws
```

output:

```
2 1212 greensdsdappleded
1 123 bardws
```

First row contains 'green' and 'apple' (2)
Second row contains nothing.
Third row contains 'bar' (1)

Thats all I would like to know.

The code (By Mr. Barmar):

```
grep -F -o -f a.txt b.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

But it need to be modified.

Comment: Does it have to be `grep` ?

Comment: No. Anything can be, if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1]; next} {t=0; for (i in A) t+=gsub(i,"&",$2)} t{print t, $0}' file1 file2
```

Comment: It is running since 15 min, thats why I would like to get a solution with grep. Mr. Barmar helped me with the last problem, and it worked like a charm. 112M rows vs 50k, and the running time was around 3minutes. Now the list is way shorter but its still running...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
awk '
NR==FNR { list[$1]++; next }
{
    cnt=0
    for(word in list) {
        if(index($2,word) > 0) 
            cnt++
    } 
    if(cnt>0) 
    print cnt,$0
}' a.txt b.txt
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat a.txt
green
apple
bar
```

```
$ cat b.txt
1212 greensdsdappleded
12124 dfsfsd
123 bardws
```

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR { list[$1]++; next }
{
    cnt=0
    for(word in list) {
        if(index($2,word) > 0)
            cnt++
    }
    if(cnt>0)
        print cnt,$0
}' a.txt b.txt
2 1212 greensdsdappleded
1 123 bardws
```